# How to use GroupFormatter with ObjectListView control

Tags: vb.net, objectlistview

I cannot seem to find anywhere, any examples on how to make use of the GroupFormatter delegate to allow me to add footers to my groups when using the ObjectListView control.

Does anyone have any examples that could demonstrate this?  I want to remove the text from the group header and add a footer (different text per footer).  As well as changing font, etc.

Any examples would be very helpful.

Comment: Okay, I have worked out how to add the footer, but I can only add the same footer to each group.  How can I add a footer within a loop? My code is: OlvColumn1.GroupFormatter = Sub(group As OLVGroup, parms As GroupingParameters)
                                                group.Footer = tempDT.Rows(x)("body").ToString
                                            End Sub

Comment: You should refine/edit your question or ask a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can analyze the code for the

```
public void MakeGroupies<T>(T[] values, string[] descriptions, object[] images, string[] subtitles, string[] tasks)
```

[method](http://moneywentwhere.googlecode.com/svn-history/r140/branches/MwwGraph/ObjectListView/ObjectListView.cs) of the ObjectListView class. That explicitly sets the *GroupKeyGetter*, *GroupKeyToTitleConverter* and *GroupFormatter* property delegates.

This is C# but your VB adaptation should be straightforward. I am using this small test class as the object type to bind to the list view.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private readonly string _s;
    private readonly float _f;

    public TestClass( string p1, float p2 )
    {
        this._s = p1;
        this._f = p2;
    }

    [OLVColumn(DisplayIndex = 1, Name="S", Title="String")]
    public string S {get {return this._s;}}
    [OLVColumn( DisplayIndex = 2, Name = "F", Title = "Float" )]
    public float F {get {return this._f;}}
}
```

So as not to manually define column traits I am using attributes inside the bound object and a

```
BrightIdeasSoftware.Generator.GenerateColumns( this.olv, typeof( TestClass ) );
```

call in the form/user control where I am using the list view. In fact here is the method that completely isolates ObjectListView configuration:

```
        void SetData( TestClass[] objects )
        {
            // build list columns
            Generator.GenerateColumns( this.olv, typeof( TestClass ) );
            // use groups and make current column the priimary sort column
            this.olv.ShowGroups = true;
            this.olv.SortGroupItemsByPrimaryColumn = false;
            // loop through columns and set properties            
            foreach( OLVColumn col in this.olv.Columns )
            {
                col.Groupable = true;
                col.Sortable = true;
                if( col.Name == "F" )
                { 
                    col.MakeGroupies<float>( new float[] { 10f, 100f, 1000f }, new string[] { "<10", "10-100", "100-1000", ">1000" } );
                }
                else if( col.Name == "S" )
                {
                    col.UseInitialLetterForGroup = false;
                    //
                    col.GroupKeyGetter = ( obj ) =>
                    {
                        TestClass tc = (TestClass)obj;
                        switch( char.ToLower( tc.S[0] ) )
                        {
                            case 'a':
                            case 'e':
                            case 'i':
                            case 'o':
                            case 'u': return true;
                            default: return false;
                        }
                    };
                    //
                    col.GroupKeyToTitleConverter = ( o ) => { bool b = (bool)o; return b ? "vowel" : "consonant"; };
                    //
                    col.GroupFormatter = ( /*OLVGroup*/ group, /*GroupingParameters*/ parms ) => 
                    { 
                        string s = string.Format ("{0} {1}", group.GroupId, group.Id);
                        //group.BottomDescription = "BottomDescription: " + s;
                        //group.TopDescription = "TopDescription: " + s;
                        group.Footer = "Footer: " + s;                        
                    };

                }

            }
            //
            this.olv.RebuildColumns();
            //
            this.olv.SetObjects( objects );
        }
```

You will definitely have one different footer per each group.

Comment: Hi there, I know it has been quite a while since you posted this answer for me, but I ventured down another path to try and achieve a much easier solution.  Seemed to work well until I needed to add additional functionality into my ListView and thus I have ended up back at the same spot - but with a little more knowledge now.  Anyway, I still (unfortunately) cannot seem to get my head around your code and I still only get the same footer for each grouped item.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, but was hoping you could possibly break your example down a little simpler please.

Comment: Okay, nevermind...turns out trial and error, a little code conversion and some research goes a long way.  I had my groupformatter sitting inside my data population loop, so it was returning the last footer data each time. I will mark your answer as accepted as your code definitely put me on the right track. I used it in conjunction with this link [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads105/sourcecode/windows/control/listview/432156/ObjectListViewDemo/MainForm.cs__.htm) Thanks again!